# How do I just JavaScriptSerializer to deserialize JSON defined at runtime

Tags: c#, json

I am receiving JSON data from an external source where I may receive multiple different things and I need to be able to parse them at runtime to determine what I'm receiving (instead of simply deserializing to a pre-built object).

I have been able to deserialize to a Dictionary of strings:

```
var dict = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json)
```

I can then do logic such as:

```
if(dict.ContainsKey("MyItem"))
{   
    doA();
}
if(dict.ContainsKey("UnknownItem"))
{
    setError();
}
```

However, **this will only work if all the items in the JSON object are strings**. How do I get this to work with arbitrary types?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use Dictionary for the type that is deserialized into. This will cause the Deserializer to build the correct native types, you can then cast them to your types as needed.

- json string -> C# string
- json number -> C# int (if no decimal point)
- json number -> C# decimal (if decimal point)
- json boolean -> C# bool
- json list -> C# ArrayList
- json dict -> C# Dictionary

Here's an example that illustrates all the type conversions:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace JsonDeserialize
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         string test = 
            "{" +
            "    \"string_type\":\"test_string\",\n" +
            "    \"int_type\":42,\n" +
            "    \"float_type\":3.141592654,\n" + 
            "    \"bool_type\":true,\n" + 
            "    \"list_type\":[\n" +
            "        \"list_one\",\n" +
            "        \"list_two\"\n" +
            "    ],\n" +
            "    \"dict_type\":{\n" +
            "        \"dict_one\":\"dict_one\",\n" +
            "        \"dict_two\":\"dict_two\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}\n";


         var dict = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<
            Dictionary<string, object>>(test);

         string result_string = "";
         int result_int = 0;
         decimal result_float = 0.0M;
         bool result_bool = false;
         ArrayList result_list = new ArrayList();
         string result_list_one = "";
         string result_list_two = "";
         Dictionary<string, object> result_dict = new Dictionary<string,object>();
         string result_dict_one = "";
         string result_dict_two = "";

         if (dict.ContainsKey("string_type"))
         {
            result_string = (String)dict["string_type"];
         }
         if (dict.ContainsKey("int_type"))
         {
            result_int = (int)dict["int_type"];
         }
         if (dict.ContainsKey("float_type"))
         {
            result_float = (decimal)dict["float_type"];
         }
         if (dict.ContainsKey("bool_type"))
         {
            result_bool = (bool)dict["bool_type"];
         }
         if (dict.ContainsKey("list_type"))
         {
            result_list = (ArrayList)dict["list_type"];
            result_list_one = (String)result_list[0];
            result_list_two = (String)result_list[1];
         }
         if (dict.ContainsKey("dict_type"))
         {
            result_dict = (Dictionary<string,object>)dict["dict_type"];
            result_dict_one = (String)result_dict["dict_one"];
            result_dict_two = (String)result_dict["dict_two"];
         }


         ////////////////// TEST //////////////////
         // Below here is just a check of the data coming out
         string expected_string = "test_string";
         int expected_int = 42;
         decimal expected_float = 3.141592654M;
         bool expected_bool = true;
         string expected_list_one = "list_one";
         string expected_list_two = "list_two";
         string expected_dict_one = "dict_one";
         string expected_dict_two = "dict_two";

         Console.WriteLine("Results...");
         if (result_string == expected_string)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("String Passed");
         }
         else
         {
            Console.WriteLine("String Failed");
            Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result_string);
         }

         if (result_int == expected_int)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Int Passed");
         }
         else
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Int Failed");
            Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result_int.ToString());
         }

         if (result_float == expected_float)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Float Passed");
         }
         else
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Float Failed");
            Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result_float);
         }

         if (result_bool == expected_bool)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Bool Passed");
         }
         else
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Bool Failed");
            Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result_bool);
         }

         if ((result_list_one == expected_list_one) &&
            (result_list_two == expected_list_two))
         {
            Console.WriteLine("List Passed");
         }
         else
         {
            Console.WriteLine("List Failed");
            Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result_list_one + " " + result_list_two);
         }

         if ((result_dict_one == expected_dict_one) &&
            (result_dict_two == expected_dict_two))
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Dict Passed");
         }
         else
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Dict Failed");
            Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result_dict_one + " " + result_dict_two);
         }

         Console.WriteLine("Test Complete");
      }
   }
}
```